# error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

I have a simple console app in .net core and I try to compile it with "dotnet build dirs.proj" but "I get : error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project."

If anyone has any idea, please share your thoughts!

This is the dirs.proj, it is quite simple.

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="Directory.Build.props" />
  <Import Project="Directory.Build.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectFile Include="ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The targets file does not have the Build defined. However, if I define something that's like  it does not do anything.

Thanks in advance for any idea or example.

Comment: What do you want the project to do? Build the other project(s)? MSBuild projects are just scripts that define the build logic, msbuild just executes them. If you don't define any logic in the file, it will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> The targets file does not have the Build defined.

When you use command like `dotnet build dirs.proj`, dotnet.exe will try to find the target named `build` in `dirs.proj` file. You should define the `build target` it **directly** in `dirs.proj` file or in the `xx.targets` file. Or you'll get the error MSB4057...

> However, if I define something that's like it does not do anything.

I assume you're trying to build the ConsoleApp1 project by command `dotnet build dirs.proj`, if so, the content in the dirs.proj file should be:

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="Directory.Build.props" />
  <Import Project="Directory.Build.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectFile Include="ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="build"> 
    <Message Text="Custom build starts..." Importance="High"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectFile)"/>
 </Target>
</Project>
```

You can use [msbuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2019) in the defined `build target`, and it will compile and build the consoleApp1 project for you.

**In addition:**

1.According to your script, your targets file, props file and the dirs.proj file should locate in solution dir

2.If you have many projects in the solution directory, you can try using wildcard to include them all:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectFile Include="**/*.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

3.For msbuild task, you can specify properties when using this task. You can specify the output path, configuration(debug or release), assembly name...

4.See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets), actually the `Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.targets` are something will work even we don't import them explicitly.

Hope it helps :)